# Finding newest file in directory

Tags: perl

I am trying to build a code that finds the newest file in a directory. I've searched up some solutions but I still cannot get the code to work. I am trying to find the most recent xml file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $dir_INFO      = '/local/nelly/INFO';
my $dir_InfoNames = '/local/data/InfoNames';

#Open INFO
opendir( DIR, $dir_INFO ) or die "can't opendir INFO";
my @files = grep { !/\./ } readdir(DIR);
foreach my $file (@files) {
    my $dir3 = "/local/nelly/INFO/$file/XML";
    opendir( DIR, $dir3 ) or die "can't opendir XML";
    my @files2 = grep { /.xml/ } readdir(DIR);
    for my $files2 (@files2) {
        open( FILES2, "<", "/local/nelly/INFO/$file/XML/$files2" ) or die "could  not open $files2 \n";
        while (<FILES2>) {
            #sort by modification time
            my %new = map( ( $_, "$dir3\\$_" ), my @xmls );
            @xmls = sort { $new{$a} <=> $new{$b} } @xmls;
            print "$xmls[0]";
            my $locations = $xmls[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`File::stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/stat.html) to get the object representation to sort a list of files by `mtime`.

Note, in order to [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) a file, one must provide a system logical reference to it.  In other words, a full path might be required.  I therefore will often use a file [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) to get the list since that will automatically include the path information in the filename.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::stat;

my @files = sort {stat($a)->mtime <=> stat($b)->mtime} glob('*.pl');

print "Youngest = $files[0]\n";
print "Oldest   = $files[-1]\n";
```

Comment: `glob('*.xml')` since OP is trying to find XML files?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Linux, and is it acceptable to use external processes? If so, then you could use this:

```
# list files in folder with 'ls' command, use '-c' option to sort by creation time
open(F, "ls -ct1 |");
# process lines that get returned one by one
while(<F>) {
    chomp();
    print "$_\n";
}
close(F);
```

Comment: Another issue that I'm having, is that it does not do it in this directory "/local/nelly/INFO/$file/XML/$files2". I don't know why but it keeps doing the files on the Desktop.My code keeps popping up as first.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Filelist = `ls -t`; $NewestFile = $Filelist[0];
```